# CSOM ListCollectionItems count based on folder path performance issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I have a design requirement to get total count for ListItemCollection based on Files specified by Folder Path. I currently have the following code in place:

```
using (ClientContext spClientContext = AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _clientId, _clientSecret))
{
    if (spClientContext != null)
    {
        int totalCount = 0;
        
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = getSiteUrlAbsolutePath(siteUrl) +
            "/Shared Documents/" + folderPath;

        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope="RecursiveAll">" +
                                "<Query>" +
                                    "<Where>" +
                                        "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq>" +
                                    "</Where>" +
                                "</Query>" +
                            "</View>";

        List list = spClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        spClientContext.Load(listItems);

        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        if (listItems != null && listItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
            {
                if (item.FileSystemObjectType.Equals(FileSystemObjectType.File))
                {
                    totalCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to be a pretty simple query to me. I am not loading a bunch of parameters etc. However, it is current taking the following time to execute:

```
Total Count = 403
Execution Time =  ~ 1276 ms
```

This seems exceptionally long for a simple query? Is there any obvious ways I can optimize the code?

Edit [reply to @Darshani Jayasekara]:

Updated to show isolated time logging:

```
using (ClientContext spClientContext = AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _clientId, _clientSecret))
{
    if (spClientContext != null)
    {
        int totalCount = 0;
        
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = getSiteUrlAbsolutePath(siteUrl) +
            "/Shared Documents/" + folderPath;

        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope="RecursiveAll">" +
                                "<Query>" +
                                    "<Where>" +
                                        "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq>" +
                                    "</Where>" +
                                "</Query>" +
                            "</View>";
                            
        // ************ Start Execution Time Logging ***************************************************************                            
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();             

        List list = spClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        spClientContext.Load(listItems);

        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    
        // ************ Stop Execution Time Logging ***************************************************************     
        stopwatch.Stop();
        
        Debug.WriteLine("Execution time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");       

        if (listItems != null && listItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
            {
                if (item.FileSystemObjectType.Equals(FileSystemObjectType.File))
                {
                    totalCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Execution time for 5 runs:

```
Execution time: 1348 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1125 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1447 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1102 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1402 ms. Total Count = 403
```

Comment: In which line you get the performance hit, is it the executequery or the loop?

Comment: @DarshaniJayasekara Thanks for the reply. I edited the original post indicating where the execution time logging starts and stops. The bulk of the time occurs isolated to 4 lines of code in which are the core CSOM API calls.